# Install ubuntu from current system state

Tags: system-installation, backup

I just installed ubuntu and installed all the necessary softwares that I normally use, for example browsers, editors etc. Also I did all the customizations that I like and so on.

Now I want to make an image/backup(I don't know what its called) of my current system. Next time, if I want to to install ubuntu on a new pc, I want to use my current image/backup so that all the software installation, customization are already there. So I don't want to do the installation of the softwares, customizations everytime I install ubuntu.

Finally, it would be like taking a snapshot of my current state of the system and when I install another one from this snapshot, new one should be exactly like the same as the current one. Hope I explained properly. Anyway, is there any way to do this?

Comment: Sure, but I would advice against it. That image does NOT help you when you want to upgrade to a newer Ubuntu. I would advice to type the commands you use to alter your system and add them to a text file so you can execute that post-install. In my experience that is the easiest, least troublesome method to re-install. Recreating that image is far more work; you need to re-do it every time you decide to add or remove software, or when you alter a setting.

Comment: The customizations won't be there and I don't mind about the newer versions.